# My Switch's SVI is down

Tags: cisco

I added a SVI interface in my Switch-`3560 24PS`, and I send `no shutdown`  , but when I `show ip interface brief`, there shows down.

```
Vlan100                10.10.10.1      YES manual down                  down
```

why?

how can I up it?

[image]

Comment: Have you added the layer 2 VLAN? `conf t` - `vlan 100` - `end` - `wr mem`. An access port or trunk port will have to forward the VLAN before it comes online after that.

Comment: you see the Switch0 and Switch1, the link between them is a trunk link.

Comment: You are right, i missed that. Is it online after you have added the layer 2 VLAN?

Comment: post your configurations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if you add a SVI, you should add the relevant Vlan.

in you scene, you should add vlan 100 in the config mode:

```
#(config)vlan 100
```